# passing value with special character to function onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

im breaking my head to figure out why i can´t pass a value with special characters to a function.

on the onclick event the value shows ok but on receving this value in the function has remove the special character \

**variable value: app\xpto**

**receiving in the function: appxpto**

how can i receive the complete value with special characters?

can someone give me a hand?

```
onclick="changeUserPictureInParent('http://mysite?f=@p.num'); 
         ToUser(\'@ViewBag.ID.ToString() \',\'@ViewBag.temp.ToString()\', \'@Html.Raw(p.Name)\');">


function ToUser(id, t, name) {
}
```

Note: im using Razor Engine

Comment: Avoid using inline javascript at all costs, this can lead to security issues and is also an anti pattern.

Comment: Why are you escaping `'` simply use `ToUser('@ViewBag.ID.ToString()','@ViewBag.temp.ToString()', '@Html.Raw(p.Name)');`

Comment: @Satpal. because this was one of several method i try to put this to work..  If i simply use this i receive in my function the variable value without the caracter \

Comment: @fmsf I would agree with you about inline js but why it lead to security issues?

Comment: @albanx it's easy to inject stuff there. A good practice is to actually disable all inline scripting https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Answer (score 0):

Ok. i found a solution for my problem.

Instead using onclick event. i use jquery .click event.

using my variable value like a data-attribute and then on click i select the value from my data attribute.

like this.

```
<div class="change" data-attr="@Html.Raw(Name)"></div>


 $(".change").click(function () {
                var a = $(this).attr("username");
            });
```